# KENDOUI grid in MVC: Is there a way to hide filters on some columns?

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using a KENDO UI grid in MVC.NET.

The grid is configured to show a column filter for each column.

Some of my columns are not filterable, though, so I want to hide the filter.

Is there a way to configure this from the C# side? (Not using CSS or JS).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your code, you probably have something like:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<%: Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductID).Groupable(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice);
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitsInStock);
    })
    .Groupable()
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Grid"))
    )
%>
</asp:Content>
```

If you want `ProductID` column not being filterable, you should say:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<%: Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductID).Groupable(false).Filterable(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice);
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitsInStock);
    })
    .Groupable()
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Grid"))
    )
%>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are not setting up the columns, you could hide the filter buttons after the grid is initialized, such as in the databound event.  Here's one way, hiding the filter button on a specific field:

```
$("#MyGrid").find(".k-header[data-field='Pct_positive']").find(".k-grid-filter").css("visibility","hidden");
```

To hide them all...

```
$("#MyGrid").find(".k-header").find(".k-grid-filter").css("visibility","hidden");
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you would have to be able to set the `columns.filterable` configuration property to 'false' for those columns that you don't want filtered, as it defaults to 'true' (see Docs: [columns.filterable](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#columnsfilterable-booleandefault))

Whether you can do this from the C# side will depend on how the Kendo Grid is being initialised in your code.

Comment: I think that columns.filterable applies to all columns. There isn't a way to set the individual columns that I can find.

Comment: To specify per column you need to provide an entry in the 'columns' array with the filterable attribute set to false. Again, this may not be possible depending on how your code is set up to create the grid

Answer (score 0):

I didn't mention it in the question, but I was using the AutoGenerate() feature of the grid, so then there is no easy access to the *Filterable* setting.

One workaround for that case is:

```
var gb = Html.Kendo().Grid(data).Name("test");
gb.Columns(columns => { columns.AutoGenerate(true); });

// !!! Hide filter for first column in grid.
gb.Columns( (columns) => { (columns.Container.Columns[0] as IGridBoundColumn).Filterable=false;  });

gb.Filterable(filtering => filtering.Enabled(true));

gb.DataSource(ds => ds
                .Ajax()
                .ServerOperation(true)
                .Model(model => model.Id("A"))
                );
gb.Render();
```

Answer (score 0):

for the client side (jquery) kendo grid you can put filterable: false, for the individual column after putting  filterable: true, for the whole grid.

eg.

field: "Margin01",
width: 40,
filterable: false,
title: "0-"